# Font recognition in wine?

Tags: fonts, wine

I'm currently developing an app to run under linux with wine, that needs to display (only display, no input) text using CJK fonts. What amuse me is the way Microsoft fonts somehow linked to each other, for example:
if I use winetricks to install Tahoma only, and run it, it show boxes for characters that cannot be displayed, and then when I install required font, e.g: MingLiu, the text rendered correctly, even though I chose only Tahoma as the default font.

The conclusion I thought is, somehow Microsoft fonts linked to each other when one try to render characters it can't render, somehow like this logic:
"try using Tahoma, if it can't render some characters, render them using other font that can (e.g: MingLiu), while still render the latin characters using Tahoma". Strangely, this is not happen when I use other CJK font that not Microsoft's, e.g: Hanazono (http://fonts.jp/hanazono/), even though Hanazono can render some characters that needs to display. If I choose Tahoma or any other font, it will never be able to render CJK characters, even though Hanazono is present in current wineprefix.

The steps that I use to reproduce this "phenomenon":

1. Start with clean wineprefix (I use winetricks to delete all wineprefixes)
2. From winetricks, install Tahoma
3. Run the app
4. Notice the garbled or boxes characters that cannot be rendered
5. Close the app, copy required font (e.g: MingLiu) to windows/Fonts dir in wineprefix directory
6. Rerun the app
7. Notice the perfectly rendered characters
8. Repeat step 1-4
9. Close the app, copy alternative font that should be able to render the text correctly (e.g: Hanazono) to windows/Fonts dir in wineprefix directory
10. Rerun the app
11. Notice the still garbled or boxes characters

I don't really know where to start to find out the workaround about this, whether it's somekind of wine-feat, or some font-specific trivia. The most simple solution is to embed Microsoft fonts, but since it will raise legal issues, I prefer to use third party fonts that I'm freely able to use. Any information will be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googling today and then I found this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms901083.aspx

It seems that "font linking" (the terms used to define the characteristic I looked for) works by defining some registry value, and after experimenting on regedit, adding new MultiString value named "DejaVu Sans" in HKLM-Software-Microsoft-WindowsNT-FontLink-SystemLink, with value:

```
HanaMinA.ttf, HanaMinA
HanaMinB.ttf, HanaMinB
```

I'm able to link DejaVu Sans with Hanazono fonts to render CJK characters DejaVu Sans can't render.

It should be noted that this experiment only works on wine, because in Windows, somehow font linking works "automagically" without need to define registries manually, which might lead to misdirection in believing same text rendering would look identical while running under wine.

Answer (score 0):

When the above doesn't work try this.

```
wine regedit
```

Navigate to:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wine\Fonts`

See if you've got a subkey called: `Replacements`

If so - you can safely delete that subkey **only**.